# Remove space before and after in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm attempting to write a macro for Outlook (never written a macro, or VBA for that matter) that will remove the space before and after the text that I have selected.

This is what I've cobbled together from examples that I've found:

```
Sub FixParagraphSpacing()
    Dim objOL As Application
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objSel As Object

    Set objOL = Application
    Set objDoc = objOL.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

    objSel.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
    objSel.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
End Sub
```

The problem is that the code executes and **almost** nothing happens. The body of the email isn't affected, but I'm not able to remove the spacing before and after manually anymore because Outlook thinks it's already been done.

What am I missing here?

**Update**

Here is my updated code, based on @KevinPope's answer:

```
Sub FixParagraphSpacing()
    Dim objOL As Application
    Dim sel As Object

    Set objOL = Application
    Set sel = objOL.ActiveInspector().WordEditor.Application.Selection

    For Each para In sel.Paragraphs
        para.SpaceBefore = 0
        para.SpaceAfter = 0
    Next para
End Sub
```

Before I run the code, here's what I see under Line and Paragraph Spacing:

[image: Remove Spacing]

And here's what I see after I run the macro:

[image: Add Spacing]

Unfortunately, other than this, **no visible change is made in the body of the email.**

---

Screenshot of text per request:

[image]

Comment: Is this spacing as in the space (or tab) character?  Or as in the space between lines of text (line height)?

Comment: @KevinPope, Line height.

Comment: Thanks for adding that, James.  To confirm, there's no empty line between the text (ie, you can only type on the lines you've already typed on).  Looks just like double spacing, but your shots from the Line and Paragraph Spacing tab show single spacing.  Do you have any other add-ins or macros that would enforce this behavior?

Comment: @KevinPope, no other add-ins or macros. If I highlight the text and use the paragraph spacing drop down to `remove space before paragraph` and `remove space after paragraph`, it looks as it should. That's what's so weird about this whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same problem.
When running the macro, it does seem to update the values (space before/after to 0), but doesnt apply the settings to the selected text.

But then adding the SpaceBeforeAuto = False worked...

```
Sub FixParagraphSpacing()
    Dim objOL As Application
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objSel As Object

    Set objOL = Application
    Set objDoc = objOL.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

    objSel.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
    objSel.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    objSel.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
    objSel.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfterAuto = False

    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using "Selection.WholeStory" before you set the paragraph formatting. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should sort out the line spacing before and after a selected Paragraph:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim objOL As Application
    Dim sel As Object

    Set objOL = Application
    Set sel = objOL.ActiveInspector().WordEditor.Application.Selection

    sel.Paragraphs(1).SpaceBefore = 0
    sel.Paragraphs(1).SpaceAfter = 0
End Sub
```

Let me know if this doesn't work and we can iterate on it.